Retirement of Azure SQL Database APIs 2014-04-01
I am referencing this MS document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/recommendedelasticpools/databases?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template for "Microsoft.Sql/servers/recommendedElasticPools" endpoint, it says that this endpoint is created by default with the resource but to reference this endpoint we need 2014-04-01 API which is going to be deprecated, so I would like to understand if we want to use this endpoint how we can do?
ElasticPool
Requesting for a solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please use the latest stable API version 2021-11-01 for elastic pools.

For more information, please read this official documentation.

I am referencing this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/recommendedelasticpools?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template. I am not able to find the latest API version available.

Please follow this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/retirement
